# Disassemble command 8E C0

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm, mov

I need to disassemble command 8E C0, can you help me?

I already made this:

First byte 8E = 10001110b it's mov sr,reg/mem

But I don't know what to do with the second byte 11000000

Comment: If the second operand is mem, I guess this is an address.

Answer (score 9):

You can wade through the intel docs to work it out yourself, or you can use a disassembler which is far easier. The answer is:

```
mov ES, EAX
```

I use yasm, and did the following:

```
# assemble the two bytes:
echo 'lbl: db 0x8e, 0xc0' | yasm -f elf - -o tmp.o

# disassemble the output:
objdump -d -M intel tmp.o
```

If you want to do this by hand, the bytes can by interpreted as follows.

`8E` corresponds to this instruction in the Intel instruction set reference:

> 8E */r* ... MOV *Sreg,r/m16* ... Move *r/m16* to segment register

The `/r` indicates that the following byte is a "Mod R/M" byte. The description of the instruction indicates that we should interpret the *Reg/Opcode* part as a segment register which will be the destination and the the *Mod* and *R/M* parts will indicate the source. Seperating out the bits, *Mod* is the top two bits (`11b`), *Reg* is the next three (`000b`) and *R/M* the bottom three bits (`000b`).

Looking up in the appropriate table, *Mod* of `11` indicates a register operand, with *R/M* denoting `EAX` (or `AX` in 16-bit mode) and `000` for *Reg* when referring to a segment register is `ES`.

Comment: EAX is the Extended version of the AX register for 32 bit x86 assembly.

Comment: @user785415: `mov es,eax` and `mov es,ax` have exactly the same effect on 32-bit processors according to the intel docs; the 16-bit operand-size prefix isn't required and the instruction will execute faster if left out. An assembler _may_ map the use of `ax` instead of `eax` into the addition of the 16-bit operand-size prefix.